# Send Petsc sequential matrix to another MPI rank

Tags: petsc, mpi

I am doing specific tests on matrices, so forgive me if this question doesn't seem related to Petsc typical use.

I have a `SEQAIJ` matrix on one process and I need to send it to another one. Is there a Petsc routine that enables this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think PETSc supports it. PETSc really thinks in parallel, so it converts at most between distributed matrices and sequential matrices through submatrix taking operations. I would MatGetArray and send that with an MPI call.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I used MPI calls and it worked ok.